# How to extract and replace columns with a multi-character delimiter?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I got a file with `^$` as delimiter, the text is like :

```
tony^$36^$developer^$20210310^$CA
```

I want to replace the datetime.
I tried `awk -F '\^\$' '{print $4}' file.txt | sed -i '/20210310/20221210/'` , but it returns nothing. Then I tried the awk part, it returns nothing, I guess it still treat the line as a whole and the delimiter doesn't work. Wondering why and how to solve it?

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, please edit your question and add expected sample output also in your question.

Comment: Provide expected result, i do not understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to replace 20210310 by 20221210 in the text file? If yes, then will a simple grep suffice? If not,, why?

Comment: looks like the OP abandoned this question..

Comment: The command in your question wouldn't just return nothing, it'd also print an error from the sed script and 2 warnings from  the awk script. It's important when asking for help with any code to tell us about any error and/or warning messages you get when trying to execute the code. If you google those messages, though, you'll quickly find answers to your problems.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be:

```
sed 's/\^\$/\n/g; s/20210310/20221210/g' -i file.txt
```

which will modify the file to separate each section to a `new line`.

If you need a different delimiter, change the `\n` in the command to maybe space   or `,` .. up to you.

And it will also replace the date in the file.

If you want to see the changes, and really modify the file, remove the `-i` from the command.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your `awk` command, I get these warnings:

```
awk: warning: escape sequence `\^' treated as plain `^'
awk: warning: escape sequence `\$' treated as plain `$'
```

That explains why your output is blank: the field delimiter is interpreted as the regular expression '^$', which matches a completely blank line (only).  As a result, each non-blank line of input is without any field separators, and therefore has only a single field.  `$4` can be non-empty only if there are at least four fields.

You can fix that by escaping the backslashes:

```
awk -F '\\^\\$' '{print $4}' file.txt
```

If all you want to do is print the modified datecodes py themselves, then that should get you going.  However, the question ...

> How to extract and replace columns with a multi-character delimiter?

... sounds like you may want actually to replace the datecode *within* each line, keeping the rest intact.  In that case, it is a non-starter for the `awk` command to discard the other parts of the line.  You have several options here, but two of the more likely would be

- instead of sending field 4 out to `sed` for substitution, do the sub in the `awk` script, and then reconstitute the input line by printing *all* fields, with the expected delimiters.  (This is left as an exercise.)  OR
- do the whole thing in `sed`:

  ```
  sed -E 's/^((([^^]|\^[^$])*\^\$){3})20210310(\^\$.*)/\120221210\4/' file.txt
  ```

  If you wanted to modify `file.txt` in-place then you could add the `-i` flag (which, on the other hand, is not useful in your original command, where `sed`'s input is coming from a pipe rather than a file).

  The `-E` option engages the POSIX extended regex dialect, which allows the given regex to be more readable (the alternative would require a bunch more `\` characters).

  Overall, presuming that there are five or more fields delimited by literal '^$' strings, and the fourth contains exactly "20210310", that matches the first three fields, including their trailing delimiters, and captures them all as group 1; matches the leading delimiter of the fifth field and all the remainder of the line and captures it as group 4; and substitutes replaces the whole line with group 1 followed by the new datecode followed by group 4.